# How do I use ‘weight’ in a phrase so that it means ‘increase the portion of something’?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

I wanted to suggest the team to increase the portion of something. e.g increase it from 10% to 70%.

and I want to find a phrase that has "weight" in it.

I have searched for weight in, weight on, put weight. but it seems to me that they are not what I mean.

Can anyone please help out? Many thanks

Comment: How can a portion be described as 10%? I could have a cup of flour, and I would consider that to be a portion of flour. But 10% isn't a portion—it's a percentage. So, a *portion* could be a tenth of a cup—or 10% of a cup—but not just 10%. (Or a *portion* could be a slice of pie.)

Comment: What is wrong with just *increase the portion*? Also, if the original portion was weight based (10 grams of something), then any increase will, by definition, be an increase in weight. But perhaps I'm not understanding. Can you provide a sample sentence in which the word or phrase you want would be used?

Comment: Maybe "give the (something) extra weight"?

Comment: Instead of "portion", do you mean "proportion"?  I think you should tell us the actual context. Increase the proportion of what?  Why do you need to use the word "weight"?  @user3169 I think that is probably the correct answer. Can you write it as an answer.

Comment: @JamesK I would rather wait for some additional context in the question, to explain what the "portion of something" is.

Comment: [correction: I wanted to suggest **to** the team that x be increased]

Answer (score 0):

There are several *weighty* idioms that might be a little strained but not unreasonable here:

> [Throw your weight behind something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+your+weight+behind) (to move some heavy object)
>
> [Give more weight to something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+weight+to) (make it more important)

To encourage the team to put in *more effort*:

> Team, how about we **throw 50% more weight behind** this problem and get it done as soon as possible?

To encourage the team to make it a *higher priority*:

> Team, let's **give 50% more weight** to this problem and get it done as soon as possible.

In either of these you could use a variable figure like "10 to 70 percent" ... but, personally, I think that weakens the point you're trying to make.